# .htaccess /controller/action pattern calling twice public/index.php

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, controller, action, public

Good evening,

I tried my best to describe the issue in the title and will detail it here further :

I have an app using this URI pattern /controller/action/parameters (ie: register/complete/email:token:any_other_parameter) (parameters are exploded in my case), as long as I'm passing only the controller in the URI (ie: /register) it works fine and my index standing in the public folder /public/index.php is not called twice.

However when specifying the action for the controller /register/complete or /admin/login (for example), public/index.php is called twice.

Here is my .htaccess in the app root covoit/ and within the covoit/public folder.

Root .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /covoitudiant/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^%1 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)?/?([a-zA-Z]+)?/?(.*)? public/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&parameters=$3 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /covoitudiant/error
```

/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't quite understand the concept to resolve it on my own, about why the index.php is called twice when receiving from URI controller/action or controller/action/parameters...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

A missing file was calling my Apache rules again and thus, my Controller was called twice.

It was due to a missing audio file with a wrong path.

Also, I used Apache's vhost in order to have one .htaccess file and readjusted the rules according to my mini-framework.

Here is the result if this can help other people too :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Handle Authorization Header.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Handle Trailing Slashes.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # If not Folder or File.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
    RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z]+)?/?([a-zA-Z]+)?/?(.*)? index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&parameters=$3 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Have a nice day!